# Creat graph with one node and a list (Graphviz dot)

Tags: graphviz, dot

I m trying to creat a graph with dot graphviz, but i want to give a node and a list of nodes and then conect that node to all of the nodes in the list. For example:

`digraph G { 
list {B; C ; D} 
A -> list 
}`

Like this i will have node A conected to a node "list". I want the node A to conect to B, C and D.How can i do that?

Comment: Welcome please supply the details. Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: for example I have a node (Class) and i have a list of nodes like( Maths, Portuguese, English)
I want the node Class to conect to these 3 nodes

Comment: Some code please in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a "list reference" in dot, but you can have a single definition of edges from a node to a list of nodes:

```
digraph G {
    // define nodes, or not ...
    b[label="b node"];
    // create edge between a node and a groupof nodes
    a -> {b;c;d};
}
```

This is equivalent to:

```
digraph G {
    // define nodes, or not ...
    b[label="b node"];

    a -> b;
    a -> c;
    a -> d;
}
```

Comment: The problem is i will have to get this list from another program so i wanted to pass the argument to this function as a list already defined

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like (`bb.dot`):

```
digraph X {
z -> a
z -> b
z -> c
}
```

and create the image like: `dot -T png bb.dot > bb.png`

Comment: `digraph G { list {B; C ; D} A -> list }`
 Like this i will have node A conected to a node "list". I want the node A to conect to B, C and D.

Comment: I'm not aware of such a concept in `dot` but maybe somebody else knows something. But please add the details of what you want to the question so people don't have to look through all comments.